# What are these Negative Lumps for?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I seem to get a lot of Negative Lumps while cleaning up my Chakras. I can't use them from my backpack - do they serve any sort of purpose? Or can I just sell them for Meat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative Lumps along with Chakra Sludges can be used to buy items from the Crimbo Lumps Shop.

They can be sold for 16 Meat each.